# Calculate years based on months in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a function that takes the number of months as a parameter and does the following:

```
IF @months = 3 THEN '3 Months'
IF @months = 6 THEN '6 Months'
IF @months = 12 THEN '1 Year'
IF @months = 18 THEN '1.5 Year'
IF @months = 24 THEN '2 Year'

.... and so on
```

I can hardcode all of this using case statements but I wanted to know if there is a dynamic way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: `'2 Year'` or `'2 Years'`?

Comment: '2 Year' - the word year stays constant.

Comment: Seems like a job better handled in client code, where a nice library might even be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
DECLARE @month INT=26
SELECT CASE WHEN @month >=12 
THEN CONCAT(CAST(@month/12.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)),' Year') 
ELSE CONCAT(@month,' Months') END
```

Comment: That actually produces incorrect answers for all values of 2 thru 12.

Comment: @JeffModen could you please give an example that what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: I already did.  Try changing the "18" in your code to any value from to 2 thru 11 (and apologies for the phat phingering... the "12" in my comment was supposed to be an "11" and I missed it).  For "2", I get an answer of "2.0 Year" instead of "2 Months".  Same occurs for all other examples up thru 11.

Comment: @JeffModen Yes you are right, answer updated and thanks. but I like your answer more and +1.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  And, yes, your solution now works a treat and I've undone my down vote and upvoted it instead.  Here's how I tested your latest... SELECT CASE WHEN t.N >=12 
THEN CONCAT(CAST(t.N/12.0 AS DECIMAL(5,1)),' Year') 
ELSE CONCAT(t.N,' Months') END 
FROM dbo.fnTally(0,100)t
;

If you're interested, you can get a copy of "fnTally" at the following URL: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally

Answer (score 1):

Please try this...

```
 SELECT IIF(@month<12,CONCAT(@Month,' Months'),CONCAT(CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,1),@Month/12.0),' Year'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet shows both the calculation and what it produces for values of month between 1 and 36

```
declare @month INT = 0

while @month < 36 begin

    set @month = @month + 1

    -- This is the actual "function"

    select case when @month < 12 then concat (@month, ' month(s)')
                else concat (cast (@month/12.0 as decimal (6,2)), ' year(s)')
                end

end
```